# Text String must be rendered withn a <Text> component using react-countdown

Tags: react-native, npm, countdown

I get this error en react native

> Text string must be rendered within a <Text< component

I try to implement a new component:

https://github.com/ndresx/react-countdown#renderer

It's a countdown and I only want to implement the simplest part:

```
return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Countdown date={Date.now() + 5000} />
      </View>
    );
```

Comment: You cannot use this library in react native as it is only built for reactjs, not react native.

Comment: Thank you, I was so frustated. Any recomendation about using a countdown in react-native?

Answer (score 0):

You can use countdown component for react native, link https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-countdown-component